# I need to read a csv file in python and insert the result into a MYSQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file with the number of people infected by covid19 per country and per day. I have created an MYSQL database, a table with all the columns that the CSV file has and now I need to insert the rows into the database

This is my code and I am getting a value error cannot process the parameters

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host=,
  user="root",
  passwd=,
  database="covid19_ca"
)

#Inserting data into the database

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

dataframe = pd.read_csv("total_cases.csv")
print(dataframe)

for row in dataframe:
    print(index)
    mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO covid_per_day_per_country (date, World, Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Andorra, Angola, Anguilla, AntiguaAndBarbuda, Argentina, Armenia, Aruba, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Bahamas, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Barbados, Belarus, Belgium, Belize, Benin, Bermuda, Bhutan, Bolivia, BonaireSintEustatiusAndSaba, BosniaAndHerzegovina, Botswana, Brazil, BritishVirginIslands, Brunei, Bulgaria, BurkinaFaso, Burundi, Cambodia, Cameroon, Canada, CapeVerde, CaymanIslands, CentralAfricanRepublic,Chad, Chile, China, Colombia, Comoros, Congo, CostaRica, CotedIvoire, Croatia, Cuba, Curacao, Cyprus, CzechRepublic, DemocraticRepublicCongo, Denmark, Djibouti, Dominica, DominicanRepublic, Ecuador, Egypt, ElSalvador, EquatorialGuinea, Eritrea, Estonia, Ethiopia, FaeroeIslands, FalklandIslands, Fiji, Finland, France, FrenchPolynesia,Gabon, Gambia, Georgia, Germany, Ghana, Gibraltar, Greece, Greenland, Grenada, Guam, Guatemala, Guernsey, Guinea, GuineaBissau, Guyana, Haiti, Honduras, Hungary, Iceland, India, Indonesia, International, Iran, Iraq, Ireland, IsleofMan, Israel, Italy, Jamaica, Japan, Jersey, Jordan, Kazakhstan, Kenya, Kosovo, Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan, Laos, Latvia, Lebanon, Lesotho, Liberia, Libya, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Macedonia, Madagascar, Malawi, Malaysia, Maldives, Mali, Malta, Mauritania, Mauritius, Mexico, Moldova, Monaco, Mongolia, Montenegro, Montserrat, Morocco, Mozambique, Myanmar, Namibia, Nepal, Netherlands, NewCaledonia INT, NewZealand, Nicaragua, Niger, Nigeria, NorthernMarianaIslands, Norway, Oman, Pakistan, Palestine, Panama, PapuaNewGuinea, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, PuertoRico, Qatar, Romania, Russia, Rwanda, SaintKittsAndNevis, SaintLucia, SaintVincentAndtheGrenadines, SanMarino, SaoTomeAndPrincipe, SaudiArabia, Senegal, Serbia, Seychelles, SierraLeone, Singapore, SintMaarten, Slovakia, Slovenia, Somalia, SouthAfrica, SouthKorea, SouthSudan, Spain, SriLanka, Sudan, Suriname, Swaziland, Sweden, Switzerland, Syria, Taiwan, Tajikistan, Tanzania, Thailand, Timor, Togo, TrinidadAndTobago, Tunisia, Turkey, TurksAndCaicosIslands, Uganda, Ukraine, UnitedArabEmirates, UnitedKingdom, UnitedStates, UnitedStatesVirginIslands, Uruguay, Uzbekistan, Vatican, Venezuela, Vietnam, WesternSahara, Yemen, Zambia, Zimbabwe) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: You can use `iterrows()` here. And when you iterate over a DataFrame with `.iterrows()` you will get two sets of values back: the indices and the rows. So you need to do something like this: `for index,row in dataframe.iterrows():`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error, do you know where it fails?

That's a heck of a long query as well - could you do something like

for country in dict:
  INSERT INTO db(country) VALUE (#)

also, it looks like you're actually missing assigning the %s

I ususally use

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM `Master List` WHERE `Seniority Number` = %s"
adr = ("{}".format(search_bolus),)
mycursor.execute(sql,adr)
mycursor.commit()
```

Brought up from a comment because I couldn't figure out minimarkdown

@python_coder Hm. I'm not fully versed on how dataframes work. I'm currently reading a CSV like this

```
with open('/mnt/users.csv', "r") as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        split = line.split(",")
        name = split[0]
        ...
        line = fp.readline()
```

Then I connect to the db, and commit the change line by line.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do the `.format()` here as the module will handle the quoting.

Comment: ValueError: Could not process parameters is the error I am getting. Number of '%s' is 212 and there are 212 columns in the csv file

Comment: @mechanical_meat Oh really? Well that will make things cleaner! The real pro-tip is in the comments!

Comment: @python_coder I updated my answer above to show you how I use csvs, as I'm not well versed in dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a natural fit for [MySQL `load data` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), whose very purpose is to *efficiently* load data from a csv file into a database table.

You have a table whose columns do correspond to the csv file, so this should be as simple as:

```
load data
infile 'total_cases.csv'
into table covid_per_day_per_country 
fields terminated by ','
```

You might need to adapt the import options to the actual spec of the file. The documentation gives lots of details on all options and their possible values.

The `load data` syntax is the recommended way to import csv data into a database table. It is very efficient, and at the same time quite flexible. You should not need to do any additional processing in your application.